# Sum of completed and not completed doesn't add up correctly in the Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api, regular-expression

I have a simple funnel situation. The users start at /start/ . Some of them reach the result at /result/ and obviously some don't.

So it seems logical to me that:

```
users who went to the start page  =  
user who did see the result page afterwards
+ user who did NOT see the result page afterwards
```

However my results are

- users who went to the start page  <<  user who did see the result page afterwards  +  user who did NOT see the result page afterwards
- user who did see the result page afterwards  is smaller than users who went to the start page  and has about the same pageview ration as the API calls tell me.
- user who did NOT see the result page afterwards  is just 10% smaller than users who went to the start page

The calls are run via the spreadsheet addin to the API.

all three calls share these attributes:

- Metric: `ga:users`
- no filter
- are for the last 30 days
- Sampling: HIGHER_PRECISION

The segments differ for each call

- `users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~/start/$`
- `users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~/start/$;->>ga:pagePath=~/result/.*`
- `users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~/start/$;->>ga:pagePath!~/result/.*`

Comment: How does your data show up in Google Analytics? Is it correct? If your funnel's first step is not set as required users can get into the funnel at any step, maybe they are arriving at step 2 or higher, or maybe directly to your goal destination.

Comment: @Binarysurf Sadly I'm not sure what you mean by show up in Google Analytics. About the funnel in GA you are right. The funnel in analytics matches users::sequence::ga:pagePath=~/start/$;ga:pagePath=~/result/.* but I don't know how I should set it up for did NOT visit a certain site. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was not clear enough, I meant how does your data show up in Google Analytics web interface? Is it correct over there?

Comment: Since the normal analytics funnel don't work as strict sequence, I don't see a possiblities how I can integrate a NOT visited this site. Any hints?